# c++ Vector fetch method returns nullptr in Release but not Debug

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I currently have a resource management type system that loads objects once at startup and in the application other objects "fetch" from this system. In debug build this works perfectly, but in Release build it returns nullpointers. For example this is a section from the resource manager:

```
// Add a single mesh to the manager
bool Soft351ResourceManager::AddMesh(
    ID3D11Device* pd3Device,
    LPCTSTR meshFile,               // mesh file location   
    bool createAdjacentIndicies,
    LPCTSTR meshName,               // Unique name
    Soft351ShaderAmbient* shader            // shader for the mesh to use
)
{
    bool result;
    Soft351Mesh mesh;

    // attempt to load the mesh file
    result = mesh.Setup(
        pd3Device,
        meshFile,
        createAdjacentIndicies,
        meshName,
        shader
    );
    // if failed to load return false
    if (!result) {
        return false;
    }

    // add object to the mesh list
    m_meshList.push_back(mesh);

    return true;
}

// Get mesh by unique name
Soft351Mesh* Soft351ResourceManager::GetMesh(LPCTSTR name)
{
    // Loop through list and check the name, if match return the object
    for (int i = 0; i < m_meshList.size(); i++) {
        if (m_meshList[i].GetName() == name) {
            return &m_meshList[i];
        }
    }

    // return null
    return 0;
}
```

And this is where the error happens:

```
// --- Game objects:
// Create the player
g_player = new Soft351PlayerObject();
// Give the player a mesh from the asset manager
g_player->mesh = g_resources.GetMesh(L"player");
// give the shield pickup a mesh from the asset manager
g_player->meshShield = g_resources.GetMesh(L"shield");
// Object has alpha based texture
g_player->meshShield->alphaTexture = true;
```

It happends on `g_player->meshShield->alphaTexture = true` with the error `Exception thrown: write access violation. g_player->meshShield was nullptr.`

There is error checking on the loading of the resources and no error or message appears, and visual studio shows that resource management vectors are filled with data. but every access to it in release mode causes nullptr or similar error. What could be causing this?

Comment: This is a use your debugger answer as single-stepping `Soft351ResourceManager::GetMesh` is required to find the answer.  Make sure you build the release build with a `PDB` file and you can debug the release build.

Comment: What does `GetName()` return? If it's `LPCTSTR` you shouldn't be using `==`.

Comment: Is there any multithreading going on?

Comment: @molbdnilo its a LPCTSTR, what should i be using to compare? just noticed it does skip over even though they are the same.

Comment: @MaxLanghof No multithreading

Comment: Based on the above comments `m_meshList[i].GetName() == name` is comparing pointers not the c-strings pointed to.

Comment: @TristanCunningham: You may want to read up on 21st century C++. If you used _any_ existing string class, such as `std::string` or `CString`, `operator==` would work. `LPCTSTR` is really a C type, and while that "works" in C++ it's generally best converted into a proper string immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
m_meshList[i].GetName() == name
```

You should do

```
lstrcmp(m_meshList[i].GetName(), name) == 0)
```

Currently You are comparing pointers which apparently are differnet in debug and release build